# Idempotents element from structure constants associative algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, lie-algebras

Let be the following definition of product of an associative algebra 
$$e_{i}e_{j}={\sum}c_{ij}^{k}e_{k}$$
Is it safe to say that being an element $a= {\sum}a^{k}e_{k}$, $a$ is idempotent if and only if  $$c_{ij}^{k}a^{i}a^{j}=a^{k},$$ for all $1\leq i,\,j,\,k\leq n$?
It seems trivial to me but since I didn't find it anywhere I'm worried I miseyed something. Thanks

Comment: We need to satisfy $a^2=a$, and you wrote it down with structure constants. This is well known. However, we do not need associativity.

Comment: Yes it was just a check, thank you Burde